# How to add a file name to a column in a data frame as multiple files are merged together?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

How can I add a file_name column to a dataframe, as data is loading into the frame?  So, I want the file_name to show for every record in the dataframe.

I did some research on this, and found something that seems like it should work, but it actually doesn't load any file names, only the data in the files themselves.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

val df = spark.read.format("csv")
   .option("sep","|")
   .option("inferSchema","true")
   .option("header","false")
   .load("mnt/rawdata/2019/01/01/corp/ABC*.gz")
   df.withColumn("file_name", input_file_name)
```

What is wrong with my code here?  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The input_file_name function creates a string column for the file name of the current Spark task.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.input_file_name
val df= spark.read
      .option("delimiter", "|")
      .option("header", "false")
      .csv("mnt/rawdata/2019/01/01/corp/")
      .withColumn("file_name", input_file_name())
```

Comment: Ah!  It's working perfect now!!  Thanks you so, so, so much!!  This will save me so much time for this current project that I'm working on!!